# Need to search for @@@ in a string JavaSCript

Tags: javascript, include, indexof

```
    var inputString = '$$'; 
  //  var inputString = '$'; 


    inputString.indexOf('$') returns > -1 index when inputString is '$'. 
    inputString.indexOf('$$') returns > -1 index when inputString is '$' - this is not desired output.
```

I need something that gives true/returns value if and only if there is an exact match '$$' **within** a larger string and not 1 of the characters within it is found.

For instance 'test $$' is true
'test $' is false
'$$ test' is true
'$$ test $$' is true

I am trying to see if there's an inbuilt method in Javascript that does this.  'includes' or 'search' also have the same issue as indexOf. Any other way to resolve this, maybe with specific Regex that is not inefficient?

Comment: `'@'.indexOf('$@$')` is -1 for me; presumably your input string isn't what you think it is.

Comment: What does "together" mean in this context?

Comment: question edited

Comment: Nope - a function like that isn't built in; they return true if there's a direct match. What you're looking for is presumably `a.indexOf(b) >=0 && a!=b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit curious why you have these specific requirements, but it can be created quite fast. Your example does not match your description, the following function does what you described, "gives true/returns value if and only if there is an exact match '$$' within a larger string". If you want `false` when there is no match, just replace the return accordingly or use [RegExp.prototype.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) `/\$\$/.test("ug23487$§%fd$$s8w374") === true;`

```js
function contains(x) {
  if (this.indexOf(x) !== -1) return true;
  else return undefined;
}

String.prototype.contains = contains;

console.log(contains.call("$", "$$"));
console.log("$".contains("$$"));
console.log("ug23487$§%fd$$s8w374".contains("$$"));
```

Note that instead of using `indexOf`, almost all of the functions you mentioned could have been used here (with a small adjustment of parameters/code)